# SQL query for newest version of data

Tags: sql

I'm fairly new to SQL and trying to filter out all versions of data that aren't the newest version of that information. Here's a snippet of the table:

```
        TABLE1
PlacementID Version Usage
2066        2       4.4
2066        1       4.2
2066        0       4.1
3001        1       8.2
3001        0       7.9
5005        3       10.3
5005        2       9.9
5005        1       9.8
5005        0       9.9
```

This is what I want the query to result in:

```
        TABLE1
PlacementID Version Usage
2066        2       4.4
3001        1       8.2
5005        3       10.3
```

This is my idea which, for obvious reasons won't work:

```
SELECT PlacementID, Version, Usage
FROM TABLE1
WHERE Version = MAX(VERSION)
```

Is there some way to make the MAX function specific to the specific Placement ID that I'm looking for? Then it would work.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `subquery` to make it *correlated*:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE1 t
WHERE Version = (SELECT MAX(t1.VERSION) FROM TABLE1 t1 WHERE t1.PlacementID = t.PlacementID);
```

However, there are other options too to achieve but it requires DBMS tag to which you are using :

One of them is :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PlacementID ORDER BY VERSION DESC) AS Seq
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE Seq = 1;
```